# text highlight is not working properly while Copy-paste from word to CKEditor

Tags: css, ms-word, ckeditor

I am trying to copy paste some text from my word document. First I was not getting font styles. I have changed the

```
config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles=false;
config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles=false;
```

Now font family, size, color is working fine but the highlighted text background color is not coming. How to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have got the answer.

```
config.allowedContent=true;
```

We have to give this configuration also to get the highlighted text while copy pasting from the word.

Comment: can you add the ckeditor script here
or add where and how could i add config in my ckeditor script

Comment: You need to set it in config.js

Comment: in my ckeditor download folder i don't have config file i have "webpack.config.js" is this the file and is this a file then where to add this code.

Comment: I am using CKEditor 5

Comment: In CKEditor5 allowedContent option is not available. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#why-does-the-editor-filter-out-my-content-styles-classes-elements-where-is-configallowedcontent-true May be you need to create new plugin.